# Plotting a histogram using Python in google.colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, google-colaboratory

I am trying to plot a histogram of a column in a dataset using Python in google.colab. I use the code:

```
data['age'].hist(bins=40)
ax.set_title('age')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram of a age]

But as shown, the x axis starts from the right. How can I make it start from the left?

Comment: As you have not received an answer, I suggest that you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This includes sample data and the code that can reproduce your output (where does `ax` come from?). Based on what we see here, I would say, this should not have happened.

Comment: Maybe `ax.invert_xaxis()`?